# copy file with any extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have only been attempting to code for a few days so please forgive me for any obvious mistakes that I make.  I have searched around for a couple of days now and have not managed to find a solution to my problem, hence why I have decided to post here.

My issue:  I have managed to create a piece of script which will search in a dedicated folder and copy a file, that the user has named themselves, via input(),  into multiple other folders.  My downfall is that I can only get it to copy files with a specific extension e.g. '.docx'.  What I would like the code to be able to do is pick up the named file regardless of it's extension.

Here is the code:

```
import shutil, os, time
while True:
    FileName = input('\n Please enter the file name: ') + '.docx'
    try:
        shutil.copy('C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\Folder\\' + FileName, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder1')
        shutil.copy('C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\Folder\\' + FileName, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder2')
        shutil.copy('C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\Folder\\' + FileName, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder3')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No such file exists.  Please try again.")
    else:
        break
print("File transfer complete.")
time.sleep(2)
quit()
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What's your expected user input? Does it require full name or just part without extension?

Comment: Full name.  The script is working flawlessly at the moment, I just need it to be as foolproof as possible for the lovely older lady that will be using it.

Comment: So, do you want to search for the filename, and then, regardless of the extension, it must move the folder?

Comment: what if there are multiple files with the same filename and different extensions? Copy all?

Comment: Sorry, I knew I was being confusing.  What I would like to happen is when the user inputs the FileName, regardless of the extension, that file is moved.  so for example.  If I had a file called "invoices," I would like the user to be able to input(invoices) and the file would be copied regardless of whether it was a .docx or a .txt file

Comment: Ev. Kounis - To answer your question, in my job there will be no two documents with the same name, however, if that was the case, having someway to overcome a potential error would be nice.  It didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: you can have the same filename, different extensions (or none) in one dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `FileName` either *equals* the file's name *or startswith* the file's name + a dot. Else you cannot exclude errors with possible files without extensions, or files with the same *partial* name.

Furthermore I'd suggest to use a conditional rather then `try`/`except`; only do the action if the file actually exists, else retry the input:

```py
import shutil, os, time
while True:
    dr = 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\Folder\\'
    FileName = input('\n Please enter the file name: ')
    # see if the file exists (listing files matching the conditions)
    match = [f for f in os.listdir(dr) if any([f == FileName, f.startswith(FileName+".")])]
    # if the list is not empty, use the first match, copy it and break
    if match:
        match = match[0]
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(dr, match), os.path.join('C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder1', match))
        # etc...
        break
    else:
        print("No such file exists.  Please try again.")

print("File transfer complete.")
time.sleep(2)
quit()
```

Comment: @BaconSoftware Aaargh two typos, fixed now.

Comment: I was just about to tell you that I had to make a couple of changes but you beat me to it.  This works absolutely perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @BaconSoftware That always makes me happy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would start going about it. There are definitely things you have to be careful of like multiple files with same name and different extension, multiple dots in files and so on. I am pretty sure those two are taken into account by the script below. Take a look.

```
import shutil
import os
import time

my_dir = r'C:\users\guest\desktop\Folder'
while True:
    all_files = os.listdir(my_dir)
    all_files_and_extentions = [x.split('.') for x in all_files]
    print(all_files_and_extentions)  # -> [['mftf5_fats_LocBuckling_B-Basis_v1', 'txt'], ['mftf5_fats_static_LSET_C_v1', 'docx']

    FileName = input('\n Please enter the file name: ')
    print(FileName)  # -> mftf5_fats_LocBuckling_B-Basis_v1

    the_file_with_ext = '.'.join([y for x in all_files_and_extentions for y in x if x[0] == FileName])
    print(the_file_with_ext)  # -> mftf5_fats_LocBuckling_B-Basis_v1.txt

    for files in the_file_with_ext:
        try:
            shutil.copy(my_dir + '\\' + files, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder1')
            shutil.copy(my_dir + '\\' + files, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder2')
            shutil.copy(my_dir + '\\' + files, 'C:\\users\\guest\\desktop\\employees\\Folder3')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("No such file exists.  Please try again.")
        else:
            break   
print("File transfer complete.")
time.sleep(2)
quit()
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a rookie question but the line:          all_files = os.listdir(r'K:\MFTF5_Retrofit\LSet_C\STAT_20160824_PostBuckling\v1\02_POST-ANALYSIS\FATS')         Do I have to edit this in anyway for my system?  As the script is crashing immediately.  Thanks.

Comment: @BaconSoftware This is indeed a rookie question. You have to put your directory there. The one that has the file you want to copy.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  With that changed the script works up until the transfer point where I get "No such file exists" and then an immediate close despite the fact I have input a file that has been listed.

Comment: @BaconSoftware Are you sure that the directory you are using on the `os.listdir()` is the same with the one on `shutil.copy()`? I changed the code a bit to make sure this does not happen

Comment: Jacob has provided me with a script that works (above) but thank you for your time and effort.  I will save a copy of your script to test later on as I'm sure it will be useful for me to learn from.